# How to Create an ID column in R and Randomly Assign data to groups

Tags: r

I have a dataset called "SPIP5" in R that is just currently a list of 50 observations. Currently looking like:

| Observations |
| --- |
| 20.46 |
| 3.08 |
| 2.07 |
| 18.2 |

I created a ID column by using;

`data.frame <- tibble:: rowid_to_column(SPIP5, "ID")`

This worked however, I don't know how to randomly assign the 50 observations between two groups and keep The IDs. Does any one have any recommendations.

I'm hoping for the dataset to look like this;

| ID | Observation | Group (A or B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20.6 | A |
| 2 | 2.07 | B |
| 3 | 18.2 | B |
| ... | --- | --- |

Answer (score 0):

`sample` will help you assign two groups randomly.

```
SPIP5 <- tibble:: rowid_to_column(SPIP5, "ID")
SPIP5$Group <- sample(c('A', 'B'), nrow(SPIP5), replace = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

`dplyr` version

```
library(dplyr)

SPIP5 %>% mutate(ID = row_number(), Group = sample(LETTERS[1:2], as.numeric(n()), replace = T))
```